# Firestore Rules: Limit users using an old version?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have users using the iOS app from TestFlight that has long been deprecated! Is there a way to block them until they upgrade their app?

I haven't been able to find out documentation about what's inside the `request` — does anyone have a definitive documentation about this other than the Firebase tutorials? I find the tutorial do not exhaustively cover all the properties of this object and I am curious if there any information about the originating request!

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {      
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        function isBanned(uid) {
                return uid in [
        "3g...V2",
        "z7...w2"
        ];
        }
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && !isBanned(request.auth.uid);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The rules you included in your question are for Cloud Firestore, so I updated the tags to be for that database too. Note that Firebase has two databases, each with their own security rules language.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen!

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request

Comment: As Doug provided, there is a documentation clarifying `request`. Could you please take a look at it and check if it helps you? If not, please, add more information on what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: did you find a solution. I have exact same problem.